# jQueryUI Dialog Scroll Position Resets on Focus of Another Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar

**Issue:**

When using multiple standard jQueryUI dialogs instantiated like:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({});
$("#dialog2").dialog({});
```

If there is substantial content or a specific height has been set to cause a scroll bar,  after scrolling inside it, then focusing the opposite dialog, the scroll bar position will reset on the first one interacted with (or all other dialogs in the case of 3 or more dialogs).

**Demo of issue in question:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Drath/yGL22/

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Scroll inside one dialog.
2. Click on the opposite dialog.
3. The scroll bar position will reset in the first dialog scrolled.

**Additional:**

Looking for possible workaround as this appears to be a bug. I was not able to use any option/method/event combination to find a way around this. This appears to occur before the focus event so I wasn't able to find a work around using that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to find a solution using "_moveToTop" in the search query. There's an official bug ticket for this issue found here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9166

It has been fixed in upcoming jQueryUI version 1.11.0. If you are having this issue running on jQueryUI version 1.10.4 or below, the workaround is as follows:

After loading jQueryUI, overwrite the _moveToTop function by loading the following code:

```
$.widget('ui.dialog', $.ui.dialog, { _moveToTop: function( event, silent ) {
    var $parent = this.uiDialog.parent();
    var $elementsOnSameLevel = $parent.children();

    var heighestZIndex = 0;
    $.each($elementsOnSameLevel, function(index, element) {
        var zIndexOfElement = $(element).css('z-index');
        if (zIndexOfElement) {
            var zIndexOfElementAsNumber = parseInt(zIndexOfElement) || 0;
            if (zIndexOfElementAsNumber > heighestZIndex) {
                heighestZIndex = zIndexOfElementAsNumber;
            }
        }
    });
    var currentZIndex = this.uiDialog.css('z-index');

    var moved;
    if (currentZIndex >= heighestZIndex) {
        moved = false;
    } else {
        this.uiDialog.css('z-index', heighestZIndex + 1);
        moved = true;
    }

    if ( moved && !silent ) {
        this._trigger( "focus", event );
    }

    return moved;
}});
```

Credit goes to user joern.zaefferer via that ticket.